# how do I get the closest specific edge to a node with JGraphT

Tags: java, jgrapht

I have a Graph with nodes which are all the same type and edges with different types. Now i want to share the data of every edge of the nodes with the type x to all other edges with different types, except for other edges of type x. But i want the data to be shared only to the nearest other edges. This is very important. The edges do have all the same parent class but different child classes.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. Please provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, define 'nearest'.

Comment: with nearest i mean the shortest way to a object. Like only 2 edges between them is better then 3.